# How to concatenate a series based on a date index to form a df without losing data

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate a bunch of historical pricing data into a single data frame, but I seem to be randomly dropping portions of data.

Here is what I am trying to do:

"v" is for value, a float type

Series 1:

```
       Ticker1
Date1     v1
Date2     v2
Date3     v3
Date4     v4
.
.
.
.
Date100   v5
```

Series 2:

```
       Ticker2
Date101   v6
Date102   v7
Date103   v8
Date104   v9
.
.
.
.
Date200   v10
```

Final desired df

```
       Ticker1        Ticker2
Date1   v1               np.nan
Date2   v2               np.nan
Date3   v3               np.nan
Date4   v4
.
.
Date100 v5
Date101 np.nan          v6
Date102 np.nan          v7
Date103 np.nan          v8
Date104 np.nan          v9
.
.
.
.
Date200 np.nan         v10
```

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
data_dict = {}

for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        data_dict[ticker] = data.DataReader(ticker,'iex',start_date, end_date)
        data_dict[ticker] = data_dict[ticker].reset_index()
        data_dict[ticker]['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_dict[ticker]['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
        data_dict[ticker]['date'] = data_dict[ticker]['date'].dt.date
        data_dict[ticker].index = data_dict[ticker]['date']
        data_dict[ticker] = data_dict[ticker].drop('date', axis=1)
    except:
        pass

pricing_df = pd.DataFrame()
volume_df = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in data_dict.keys():

    temp_series = pd.Series(data = data_dict[ticker]['close'].values,
                        index = data_dict[ticker].index,
                        name = ticker
                        )

    pricing_df[ticker] = temp_series

    temp_series = pd.Series(data = data_dict[ticker]['volume'].values,
                        index = data_dict[ticker].index,
                        name = ticker
                        )

    volume_df[ticker] = temp_series
```

What I'm getting in return is essentially what I want, but with an arbitrary amount of dates cut off at the beginning of the dataset. Specifically, I have series with dates going back to 2014, but when I bring into the final dataset, but df starts in mid-2015....

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1: Joining:

I would use `join` in your case, which would easily allow for a given date to have values in both `Ticker1` and `Ticker2`, though you still have to transform them to dataframes first (as in @dportman's answer):

```
pd.DataFrame(series1).join(pd.DataFrame(series2), how='outer')

        Ticker1 Ticker2
Date1        v1     NaN
Date100      v5     NaN
Date101     NaN      v6
Date102     NaN      v7
Date103     NaN      v8
Date104     NaN      v9
Date2        v2     NaN
Date200     NaN     v10
Date3        v3     NaN
Date4        v4     NaN
```

Note: you could do the same with `merge`, but would need to add the `left_index=True, right_index=True` arguments:

```
pd.DataFrame(series1).merge(pd.DataFrame(series2), 
                            left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

## Method 2: Concatenating:

You can also use `pd.concat` on your 2 series to get the same results:

```
pd.concat([series1, series2], axis=1)

        Ticker1 Ticker2
Date1        v1     NaN
Date100      v5     NaN
Date101     NaN      v6
Date102     NaN      v7
Date103     NaN      v8
Date104     NaN      v9
Date2        v2     NaN
Date200     NaN     v10
Date3        v3     NaN
Date4        v4     NaN
```

## Sorting by datetime index:

Assuming that your dates are actual dates, or at least date strings, you can then sort by index. For instance, if it looks like this:

```
>>> df
           Ticker1 Ticker2
2018-06-25      v1     NaN
2018-06-28      v5     NaN
2018-06-26     NaN      v6
2018-07-01     NaN      v7
2018-06-24     NaN      v8
2018-06-23     NaN      v9
2018-06-29      v2     NaN
2018-06-30     NaN     v10
2018-06-22      v3     NaN
2018-06-27      v4     NaN
```

use `df.sort_index()`:

```
           Ticker1 Ticker2
2018-06-22      v3     NaN
2018-06-23     NaN      v9
2018-06-24     NaN      v8
2018-06-25      v1     NaN
2018-06-26     NaN      v6
2018-06-27      v4     NaN
2018-06-28      v5     NaN
2018-06-29      v2     NaN
2018-06-30     NaN     v10
2018-07-01     NaN      v7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your two series to dataframes and then use pandas `df.append()` method to append the two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(series1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(series2)
result = df1.append(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what this might be happening?

Comment: My guess is that you maybe have duplicate indices in the two dataframes, and then when you append those indices are only appended once and you lose the other instance. Maybe try to .reset_index() and then append the dataframes.